# Do hierarchical linear models (HLM) require random samples?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, research-design

Excuse me if this is a naive question, but do hierarchical linear models require data collected from random samples?

I ask because most of the literature I find on this topic does a poor job of explaining how the data were acquired. My assumption is that if HLM is an extension of classical inferential statistics, you need a random sample (or some varition thereof, e.g., cluster sampling, quadrat sampling, every nth item is selected after RNG for starting position in the sampling frame), full stop. I'm also assuming that HLM is used to make inferences about the larger population from which it is drawn, and not simply to examine the characteristics of the sample itself.

However, if HLM is a Bayesian approach, maybe that isn't the case?

Comment: "*My assumption is that if HLM is an extension of (...), full stop.*" Correct. HLM do not magically resolve selection bias issues.

Comment: How do I set your response as the answer? I don't see the usual checkmark next to it.

Comment: I am happy you find my comment helpful but it is not a proper answer. It is just a comment. Hopefully someone will expand on this further.